# add_column bug for Postgres with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

My migration add_column

```
class Migration_Add_post_to_post extends CI_Migration {
    public function up() {
        $fields = array(
            'post' => array('type' => 'TEXT')
        );
        $this->dbforge->add_column('posts', $fields);
    }

    public function down() {
        $this->dbforge->drop_column('posts', 'post');
    }
}
```

Codeigniter throws Database Error when code executes

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "Array" LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD Array NOT NULL ^
```

I found this issue on github https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/808. Even though the issue was closed, it seems like the bug still exists except mysql driver.

Any way to walk around that issue ?

Comment: what CI version are you using?